# Hover changing div higher in the hierarchy

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have problem with cascading.
Here's my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Jackenmen/TF27R/1/

CSS:

```
#pdorota:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pdorota">
    <div id="napisdorota">Dorota</div>
    <img id="pldorota" src="http://6best.pl/planety/dorota.png">
</div>
```

When I am hovering mouse on picture, it rotate, but when I am hovering mouse on not visible div (#napisdorota), the picture also rotates.
How must I change this code, could this rotate only when I'm hovering mouse on picture?

Comment: Yea, change your CSS from `#pdorota:hover` to `#pldorota:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add style `visiblity:hidden` on the `div` and set it back to `visible` when hovering. Note that `opacity:0` still makes your div receive mouse events.

```
#napisdorota { 
  ...
  visibility:hidden;
}
#pdorota:hover #napisdorota {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility:visible;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/TF27R/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the hover selector to target `#pldorota` **[(see JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/TF27R/2/)**:

```
#pldorota:hover {
  ...
}
```